# Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the problem? I declared variable n

```
var n = 0;

while (true) {
  var comment = document.getElementsByClassName('wall_reply_text')[n].textContent;
  
  if (comment.indexOf("публикации") == 0) {
    alert(comment);
  }
  
  n++;
}
```

Comment: What makes you so sure your HTML has any elements with that classname? You haven't provided any HTML for us to examine, so we certainly can't tell you.

Comment: We have to assume that either no such element exists your your function is running before it's loaded. Can't say without more information.

Comment: Also, `while(true)` seems a strange way to loop for this use case.

Comment: all elements including wall_reply_text exist

Comment: yes, but your `n` will quickly exceed the highest index in your array, and `while(true)` means your loop never breaks w/out add'l workarounds

Comment: if you replace the variable n with the number 1 or 2 or 3 and so on, then the code works fine

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I do prefer querySelectorAll over getElementsByClassName in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break if there is no element

```js
var n = 0, comment=""

while (true) {
  const div = document.getElementsByClassName('wall_reply_text')[n]
  if (div) comment = div.textContent;
  else break
  
  if (comment.indexOf("публикации") == 0) {
    console.log(n,comment);
  }
  
  n++;
}
```

```html
<div class="wall_reply_text">1</div>
<div class="wall_reply_text">публикации</div>
<div class="wall_reply_text">3</div>
<div class="wall_reply_text">4</div>
```

Here is a more elegant way

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.wall_reply_text')]
  .map(div => div.textContent)
  .forEach((comment,i) => {
    if (comment.indexOf("публикации") == 0) {
      console.log(i,comment);
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="wall_reply_text">1</div>
<div class="wall_reply_text">публикации</div>
<div class="wall_reply_text">3</div>
<div class="wall_reply_text">публикации</div>
```

Alternative if you just need the one index

```js
const comments = [...document.querySelectorAll('.wall_reply_text')]
  .map(div => div.textContent)
console.log(comments.indexOf("публикации"))
```

```html
<div class="wall_reply_text">1</div>
<div class="wall_reply_text">публикации</div>
<div class="wall_reply_text">3</div>
<div class="wall_reply_text">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the most likely explanation is that there are no elements with class name `wall_reply_text` when this code runs, so `document.getElementsByClassName('wall_reply_text')` returns an empty array. when you try to access index 0 in that empty array, you get `undefined`, and thus the error when trying to access `undefined.textContent`.

Comment: if I specify 0 or 1 or 2 instead of n, then there are no errors

Comment: in that case, what's probably happening is that n is growing very large since this code is executing in a while loop with no break condition.